# Show that $f$ is discontinuous.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let the sequence of function $f_{n}=\sqrt[2n+1]{x}$ (for $x\geq 0$). I've shown that it converges pointwise to $f$, that is 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 &\mathrm{for}& x=0 \\ 
1 &\mathrm{for}& x>0
\end{matrix}\right..
$$
Now how do I **show that the function $f:[0,\infty[\to\mathbb{R}$ isn't continuous**?

If we, for example, say that $f$ isn't continous at $0$ so we have
$$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0:\left | x-0 \right |<\delta\Rightarrow \left | f(x)-f(0) \right |<\varepsilon$$

or just $\left | x \right |<\delta\Rightarrow \left | f(x) \right |<\varepsilon$. And therefore it shows that it isn't continuous. Is it true what I did or did I do something absurd?

Answer (score 2):

You write the definition of continuity in a point $x=0$ and show that your $f$ doesn't satisfy it.

You can also start by writing the negation of the definition of continuity and show that $f$ satisfies this negation.

$g$ is discnotinuous at $x=x_0$ $\iff$
$$\exists \varepsilon>0\,\forall \delta>0\,\exists x :\,|x-x_0|<\delta\&|g(x)-g(x_0)|>\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

A function which is continuous must have bounded variation around any point. For you the point $0$ is the "problematic" point.

You should try to show there exist an $\epsilon$, such that for any $\delta$, $|x|<\delta$ you have $$|f(x)-f(0)|>\epsilon$$

You probably should think why this is the proper way to show $f$ is discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

To show that your function is continuous first recall that a function is continuous only if the preimage of open sets in the topology of the codomain is open sets in the topology of the domain. In your question it appears we are using the subspace topology inherited from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Notice that any neighbourhood of $0$ that doesn't include $1$ has $\{0\}$ as its preimage which is not open in the standard topology.

Another way to prove that your function is continuous is to use the standard $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments. Since $f(0)=0$ we just note that for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ there is no $\delta>0$ such that $\vert f(x)\vert<\epsilon$ for all $\vert x\vert<\delta$.

You can also prove that your function is discontinuous by using sequential continuity. Consider the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ which converges to $0$ in the domain. This maps to the sequence $f(x_n)=1$ but $f(0)=0$. So $f(x_n)$ does not converge in the codomain.